# find sum of squares after grouping two cols

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy, standard-deviation

I had a dataset that looks like this:

```
Value         Type       X_sq    
-1.975767     Weather   
-0.540979     Fruits
-2.359127     Fruits
-2.815604     Corona
-0.929755     Weather
```

I wanted to iterate through each row and calculate a sum of squares value for each row above (only if the Type matches). I want to put this value in the X.sq column.

So for example, in the first row, there's nothing above. So only (-1.975767 x -1.975767). In the second row, there's no FRUITS row above it, so it will just be -0.540979 x -0.540979. However, in the third row, when we scan all previous rows, we should find that FRUITS is already there. So we should **get the last's FRUIT's  .....  X_sq** value and calculate a new sum of squares.

```
Value         Type       X_sq
-1.975767     Weather   -1.975767 * -1.975767    = x
-0.540979     Fruits    -0.540979 * -0.540979    = y
-2.359127     Fruits    y + ( -2.359127 x -2.359127)  
-2.815604     Corona    -2.815604 * -2.815604
-0.929755     Weather   x + (-0.929755 * -0.929755)
```

I tried this and it works perfectly:

```
df['sumOfSquares'] = df['value'].pow(2).groupby(df['type']).cumsum()
```

However, now I want to group based on two cols: Such that Country and Type both match.

```
Value         Type       X_sq    Country
-1.975767     Weather            Albania
-0.540979     Fruits             Brazil      --should be grouped
-2.359127     Fruits             Brazil      --should be grouped
-2.815604     Corona             Albania
-0.929755     Weather            Chine
```

I tried this (type = themes) here:

```
df['sumOfSquares'] = df['value'].pow(2).groupby(['themes', 'suppliers_country']).cumsum()
```

However, it gives me this error even though 'types' is present in the dataset

```
----> 1 df['sumOfSquares'] = df['avg_country_tone'].pow(2).groupby(['themes', 'suppliers_country']).cumsum()
     

File /usr/local/Cellar/ipython/8.0.1/libexec/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pandas/core/series.py:1929, in Series.groupby(self, by, axis, level, as_index, sort, group_keys, squeeze, observed, dropna)
   1925 axis = self._get_axis_number(axis)
   1927 # error: Argument "squeeze" to "SeriesGroupBy" has incompatible type
   1928 # "Union[bool, NoDefault]"; expected "bool"
-> 1929 return SeriesGroupBy(
   1930     obj=self,
   1931     keys=by,
   1932     axis=axis,
   1933     level=level,
   1934     as_index=as_index,
   1935     sort=sort,
   1936     group_keys=group_keys,
   1937     squeeze=squeeze,  # type: ignore[arg-type]
   1938     observed=observed,
   1939     dropna=dropna,
   1940 )

File /usr/local/Cellar/ipython/8.0.1/libexec/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pandas/core/groupby/groupby.py:882, in GroupBy.__init__(self, obj, keys, axis, level, grouper, exclusions, selection, as_index, sort, group_keys, squeeze, observed, mutated, dropna)
    879 if grouper is None:
    880     from pandas.core.groupby.grouper import get_grouper
--> 882     grouper, exclusions, obj = get_grouper(
    883         obj,
    884         keys,
    885         axis=axis,
    886         level=level,
    887         sort=sort,
    888         observed=observed,
    889         mutated=self.mutated,
    890         dropna=self.dropna,
    891     )
    893 self.obj = obj
    894 self.axis = obj._get_axis_number(axis)

File /usr/local/Cellar/ipython/8.0.1/libexec/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pandas/core/groupby/grouper.py:882, in get_grouper(obj, key, axis, level, sort, observed, mutated, validate, dropna)
    880         in_axis, level, gpr = False, gpr, None
    881     else:
--> 882         raise KeyError(gpr)
    883 elif isinstance(gpr, Grouper) and gpr.key is not None:
    884     # Add key to exclusions
    885     exclusions.add(gpr.key)

KeyError: 'themes'
even though themes is there. Themes = type
```

Comment: `df['Value'].pow(2).groupby([df['Type'], df['Country']]).cumsum()` works in the sample you've provided.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the error occours because you are grouping a pd Series and it has no keys named `'themes', 'suppliers_country'`. To group a Series you have to pass as `groupby` arrgument another series rather then strings.
Try to concatenate string columns to group in a single Series, and group as:

```
df['sumOfSquares'] = df['Value'].pow(2).groupby(df.Type+"__"+df.Country).cumsum()
```

In alternative, you can also group by 2 different series (that I think was your first idea):

```
df['sumOfSquares'] = df['Value'].pow(2).groupby([df.Type,df.Country]).cumsum()
```

Comment: is it also possible to calculate the mean in the same way? I tried this: ```df['mean'] = df.groupby([df.themes,df.suppliers_country], as_index=False)['avg_country_tone'].expanding().mean().sort_index(level=1).droplevel(0)``` but I get an error that: ```TypeError: incompatible index of inserted column with frame index```

Comment: meanwhile, this was working: ```df['mean'] = df.groupby('themes', as_index=False)['avg_country_tone'].expanding().mean().sort_index(level=1).droplevel(0)```

Comment: have you tired `df.groupby(["Type","Country"]).mean()` ?

Answer (score 0):

You can create new helper column, here `new`, so possible use your solution with define columns names in `groupby`:

```
df['sumOfSquares'] = (df.assign(new = df['avg_country_tone'].pow(2))
                        .groupby(['themes', 'suppliers_country'])['new']
                        .cumsum())
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to merge `Type` and `Country` columns to get the total sum, use:

```
out = df.assign(X_sq=df['Value'].pow(2)).groupby(['Type', 'Country'])['X_sq'] \
        .sum().reset_index()
print(out)

# Output
      Type  Country      X_sq
0   Corona  Albania  7.927626
1   Fruits   Brazil  5.858138
2  Weather  Albania  3.903655
3  Weather    Chine  0.864444
```